# Redirect to specific page position Next.js

Tags: javascript, next.js

for some reason when i click on the link

```html
 <Link href="/mypage#mydiv" passHref>
```

I get redirected to the position of the div with id="mydiv". But if i try to access http://localhost:3000/mypage#mydiv this does not work. Any help? I need to produce a link like that to send an email withit it and so that when the receiver clicks on it gets redirected to specific page position. Thanks

Comment: Link will not work for what you are wanting.  Use Routes instead: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/reactjs-router/

Comment: I don't get how would that help me.

Comment: I just tested, it works fine. Why are u using passHref ? Is it next 13 or 12?  Have you tried /mypage/#mydiv  ? i.e. #part after /

Comment: The Link is working perfectly fine. The problem is if I try to access directly via the url writing it in the browser. I'm using next 13. Yes i think # after / will work but then i will need to create another page file in my project.